# Session Data to Model MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use C# Sessions as a way to store data(potentially editing) instead of going back to the database repeatedly, especially with repopulating lists, plus this may go across a few pages.

In ASP Web Forms I would do the following.

Code behind:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["PersonSession"] as String)
{
  Person newPerson = new Person();
}
else
{
  Person newPerson = (Person)Session["PersonSession"];
  myTextBox.Text = newPerson.Name.ToString();
}
// submitting the data chucking the data the other way
// then stored proc
newPerson.Name = myTextBox.Text;
```

Using the above I was able to populate existing textboxes and submit the data back to the session upon a submit button click.

How do I achieve this in Razor MVC 5?

**Update**
I've been trying to utilise the suggested methods in the answers below and update as I go.
Trying to store everything in session and let it display through ViewBag before everything gets dumped to the db.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["SessionObj"]))
            {
                List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
            }
            else
            {
                List<Person> People = (List<Person>)Session["SessionObj"];

                //foreach(var p in People)
                //{
                //    p.Name.ToString();
                //}
                ViewBag.PersonList = People;
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddPerson([Bind(Include ="Name")]Person person)
        {
            // add session/viewbag to list of session/viewbag
            List<Person> People = (List<Person>)Session["SessionObj"];
            People.Add(person);
            Session["SessionObj"] = People;

            return View();
        }
```

**Index**

```
@model SessionData.Models.Person
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@if (ViewBag.PersonList != null)
{
    foreach (var person in @ViewBag.PersonList)
    {
        <div>@person.Name</div>
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="AddPerson" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: If you do it for performance reason I would suggest to use Cache, it's much better.

Answer (score 3):

You normally don't want to use a *Session* within Model View Controller, as they can quickly become orphaned, which will hinder performance, but it will also dictate a persistent state.  Which violates the stateless nature of Model View Controller, so you want to ensure it is ideal.

Some alternatives would be:

- *Hidden*
- *Temporary Data*

This will potentially allow you to absolve the multiple database request.  However, if you would like to create a *Session* of your model data:

```
public class Person
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A simple model, for brevity sake.  When you call your data layer it would populate said *Model* as either an `object Person` or a collection of `Person` such as `List<Person>` for example.

Once you have said data, you would simply do the following:

```
var person = GetPeople();
Session.Add("Person", person);
```

We will use `GetPeople()` as a `List<Person>` return.  Once you've applied that `Session.Add(...)` you no longer need to call your database for that model.  You simply would do:

```
var model = (List<Person>)Session["Person"];
```

You now have the model, so you would simply do:

```
return View(model, ...);
```

Which would now all you in this case an `IEnumerable` through `Model`.  Which you can iterate through with Razor.  Another approach, would be a hard call through Razor.

```
@{
    var model = (List<Person>)Session["Person"];
    if(model.Any())
         foreach(var person in model)
         {
              <div>@person.Name</div>
         }
}
```

You can do this in several ways, so hopefully these handful of approaches help you.

Comment: what are you doing in GetPeople() ? is this a method within the controller?

Comment: Just doing a call to data layer as I mentioned below, to return a collection.

Comment: Ah right, I'm working from not having a data layer, with no link to db until final submit. Will update q with what I've got so far. Cheers for the help.

Comment: Is session not directly available in the view? Why do you need model?

Answer (score 2):

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["PersonSession"]))
{
  Person newPerson = new Person();
}
else
{
  Person newPerson = (Person)HttpContext.Current.Session["PersonSession"];
}
```

And you can use this variables directly in your html like this:

```
<div>@newPerson.Name.ToString()</div>
```

Inside "Views" folder you have "Web.config" file. Include your "Person" namespase into "Web.config" and all be fine.

But more acceptable way is put this code into your controller:

......

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["PersonSession"]))
    {
      Person newPerson = new Person();
    }
    else
    {
      Person newPerson = (Person)Session["PersonSession"];
    }

ViewBag.PersonName = newPerson.name.toString;
return View();
```

And into your razor view just use this viewBag:

```
<div>@ViewBag.PersonName</div>
```

Comment: Was about to ask is whether or not put it into the controller, your edit answered that, Beautiful, thanks for that. Can this method be used if I have multiple objects of person? So as to fill a list.

Comment: Just save this array or list into your viewBag or model and render it int the view: @foreach (var x in ViewBag.PersonNames)
    {<li>@x</li>}

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, a few things.

Your controller looks a bit wrong, seems it'll never hit the second part as you're never setting a session.

Controller Index Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["SessionObj"] != null)
            {
                List<Person> People = (List<Person>)Session["SessionObj"];
                ViewBag.PeopleList = People;
            }
            else
            {
                List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
                Session["SessionObj"] = People;
            }
            return View();
        }
```

You're Index should be split into two pages (or more) if you wish to add objects as well as display the list.

Personally I would go with Index as being an IEnumerable model to display the list and make the add model a partial view (passing in a new person object).

Where you're passing in the `ViewBag.PersonList` in the Index.cshtml foreach loop, you should be looping through against the `Model`, as that's what the Model now is when you pass the viewbag through in the AddPerson action method.

Add this to the AddPerson action method:

```
ViewBag.PeopleList = People;
            return View("Index", ViewBag.PeopleList);
```

Hope this helps, not complete and working, but should definitely further you to you're goal.